# Удаленно подключить сетевой принтер powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Добрый день. Задача стоит установить сетевой принтер 10 пользователям. про групповые политики известно, необходимо сделать это на powershell. У всех стоит 7, powershell 1.0. Укажите направление в котором искать или если завалялась исходники прошу поделиться.

Comment: А точно пошик 1-й версии? Он же вроде тока в XP был. В 7 по-умолчанию новее должен быть.

Comment: @donRumata да первой версии

Comment: @BoBo А как Вы узнали, что именно первой? `v1.0` в пути к `powershell.exe` не означает номер версии.

Comment: @donRumata мб, но это не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Если бы был ответ - я бы его оформил как ответ.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/working-with-printers?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: чтобы узнать версию powertshell выполните код `$host.Version` и скажите нам, какая цифра написана под словом `major`?